# Getting "Cannot use ref or out parameter inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression" for an "in" parameter

Tags: c#

C# 7.2 added readonly structs and the `in` modifier for method parameters. However, you get a compiler error when you try to use these structs with reference-like semantics in lambda expressions:

```
public readonly struct Point {
    public Struct(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
}

public IEnumerable<Point> FindMatching(
    this IEnumerable<Point> points, 
    in Point toMatch) {
    return point.Where(p => p.X == point.X && p.Y == point.Y);
}
```

Compiling returns an error:

> error CS1628: Cannot use ref or out parameter 'toMatch' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression.

It's not a ref or out parameter, however.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with that dup; it isn't asking why we can't use `ref`/`out` here. It is asking specifically about a C# 7.2 feature, so an answer from 2009 **cannot possibly** answer this directly

Comment: @MarcGravell And the reason is the same.  What matters is that the parameter is passed by reference, not how the referenced parameter can or can't be mutated.

Comment: `The in modifier on parameters, to specify that an argument is passed by reference but not modified by the called method.` So, in fact it's a `ref` but which will disallow the modification of the content. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-2#reference-semantics-with-value-types

Comment: @Servy I fundamentally disagree with you here

Comment: @MarcGravell How do you think the duplicate fails to answer the question?  What about it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Servy because that question explains why you can't use `ref` / `out` in a lambda. The answer to "why does it complain about `ref` / `out` when I use `in`" is simply: because `in` is actually a `ref`. Pointing to that answer *simply doesn't answer that*. Especially given that the compiler message is very confusing and doesn't help here. I'd agree that they're strongly related questions, but they're not the same.

Comment: @MarcGravell And *the explanation for why you can't  use `out/ref` applies *exactly* to `in`.  You appear to have just looked at the title and *ignored the actual answer*, which explains *why* you can't do it.  That *explanation* applies perfectly to `in`.  You have merely *stated* that the error applies, and not explained *why* the error message exists.  Saying, "no the error isn't wrong" isn't answering the question.  The duplicate, which demonstrates what would break if this were allowed *does* answer the question.

Comment: @MarcGravell The question isn't asking why the error message doesn't mention `in`.  This isn't a bug report.  It's asking *why the behavior isn't allowed*.  The duplicate answers that question.

Comment: The question states an error message and doesn't ask any question. We're left to infer whether the question is why an error is generated at all, or why *that* error is generated. Whether closing as a duplicate is correct depends on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes, `in` *is* a `ref` parameter, but with fancy semantics. The same as `out` is a `ref` parameter with fancy semantics. The compiler message could be clearer, perhaps - that might be a good [bug to log on the Roslyn github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues). But: it is correct to error. I would agree that the error should explicitly mention `in` parameters.